# How to split csv whose columns may contain , single quotes and double quotes

Tags: .net

```
favorite 
1 Given

2,1016,7/31/2008 14:22,'Geoff Dalgas',6/5/2011 22:21,http://stackoverflow.com,"Corvallis, OR",7679,351,81,b437f461b3fd27387c5d8ab47a293d35,34
```

Expected output is

```
2
1016
7/31/2008 14:22
Geoff Dalgas
6/5/2011 22:21
http://stackoverflow.com
Corvallis, OR
7679
351
81
b437f461b3fd27387c5d8ab47a293d35
34
```

Comment: Use FileHelpers, TextFieldParser or other [csv-reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any *great* CSV libraries for .NET, so first get the file into a homogeneous format (double quotes for all fields) with [CSVfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/), then use whatever .NET library you like, eg. [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

The command to do that is [`csvfix echo`](http://csvfix.byethost5.com/csvfix15/csvfix.html?echo.html)